# Logging off user after x minutes of inactivity and when the app is removed from background

Tags: ios, logout

I would like to logoff user after certain time if the app is background, also if the the app is removed from background.

In both cases I want to inform to server that user is logged out.

I think first case is possible by using timer in app delegate, How can i achieve the second case?

How to call web service when its terminated ?

Note:The main objective is to calculate "total login time". In other words how munch time user is using the app either in foreground and background .

Thank you…

Answer (score 0):

You can save date of inactive and active states of application. In next active state you can calculate time interval since last inactive state and perform needed logic.

Comment: I need to inform my server immediately when app is inactive, How can i do that ?

Comment: Send it in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method of `AppDelegate`

Comment: But when the application is terminated, How can i inform server

Comment: Read information about `applicationWillTerminate` method. FYI, `your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.`